# lstlisting color formatting constructor of a class (C++ style code)

Tags: formatting, color, listings

I'm trying to color format the constructor of a class, so that the color of the class name, which has the same name as the class function (constructor) is different to the color of the class function (constructor).

How can I have different colors for the same keyword?

```
ClassName::ClassName(){

}
```

Thank you! :)

Edit: Sorry, I'm gonna add a little more detail here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{30,30,30}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{128,128,128}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  language=C++,
  bunch_of_more_settings,
  keywordstyle = {\color{color1}},
  keywordstyle = [3]{\color{color2}},
  keywordstyle = [4]{\color{color3}},
  morekeywords = [2]{},
  morekeywords = [3]{ClassName,key2},
  morekeywords = [4]{key3,key4},
  morekeywords = [5]{key5,key6},
}

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

So color formatting works perfectly fine, all keywordstyles have the correct color, the problem is I want to have 2 different colors for the same keyword, as you would have, when writing a constructor -> ClassName::ClassName (the first one should be a class color, eg. keywordstyle[3], the second one should have a function color, eg. keywordstyle[4]. Now I was wondering if that is possible.

Thank you!

Comment: The class name is not a keyword right? Then why do you expect it would be colored? Do you want to color all the function names instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please show a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) so that we can see which (relevant) packages you're using and how you configured syntax highlighting for C++.